# How to serialize a list of type X, filled with objects of type Y, which extends X, and still get Y elements upon deserialization?

Tags: java, list, serialization, types, subclass

I have this list

```
LinkedList<ASD> list = new LinkedList<ASD>();
```

then, I add some objects which extend ASD

```
BSD bsd = new BSD(); // BSD extends ASD
list.add(bsd);
```

and serialize list.

How can I get it to serialize and deserialize teh bsd element as BSD and
not as ASD?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: in fact, I have tried a lot of things before asking, just not teh right ones. I have tried a minor example and my problem seems to come from another sauce. Maybe I just need some sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a problem. All objects that you want to serialize must be instances of classes that implement `Serializable`. `LinkedList` does it. Declare either `ASD` or `BSD` (it does not matter in your case) to implement `Serializable` and try. Everything should work.

Comment: Thanks! I should have tried some smaller test before, teh real problem seem to come not from this, but from another sauce.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by AlexR, everything is fine:

```
class ASD implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}

class BSD extends ASD {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}

LinkedList<ASD> list = new LinkedList<ASD>();
list.add(new BSD())
```

Now, if you serialize `list`, and later deserialize it, its elements will be of the correct type `BSD`.

Furthermore, the generic type argument (the `<ASD>` thing) is not saved during the serialization. The serialization procedure will only remember that `list` is a `LinkedList` object. What this means is that you can serialize an object of type `LinkedList<ASD>` and then deserialize it as `LinkedList<BSD>` (or even as e.g. `LinkedList<Integer>`). An exception can be thrown later, though, if you try to access an element of the list that cannot be cast to the newly specified generic type.

Finally, I'm just saying this is doable, not that it is a good practice :)